# Can't open google link from iframe in new window due to "cross-origin opener policy"

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, href

I have an iframe that contains a link, which looks like this:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/travel/flights/s/3nDqYBmu3h4Jfmwm6"
target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Purchase Flight</a>
```

On link click, I would like it to open a new tab or window. However, Chrome is blocking the page from loading with the following error (in the Network tab under Response):

```
cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin-allow-popups

-> This document was blocked from loading in an iframe with a sandbox
attribute because this document specified a cross-origin opener policy.
```

I haven't set any specific headers on the request, just an href link.

The link opens properly in Safari, but not Chrome. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What's the code you're using for your iframe?

Comment: @Ouroborus it's actually an iframe embedded within Notion, so I'm not hard-coding the iframe.

Comment: Notion will still necessarily generate code for the iframe. What is it generating?

Comment: @Ouroborus Ah, good question! Here it is:
`<iframe src="<EMBED_LINK>" frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-popups allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation allow-forms allow-same-origin" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>`

Comment: @Ouroborus I did notice the above error I mentioned is listed under `cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin-allow-popups` – maybe that's it?

Comment: Did you find solution to this @dominic? We have the same issue when extending Jira...

Comment: I have this problem opening a Twitter link from a OneDrive Excel sheet embedded in a Wix page. It's because Twitter has the header `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy:
same-origin-allow-popups` set, and the iframe in Wix looks like this:

`<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-popups allow-modals allow-scripts allow-pointer-lock" class="wuksD5" title="Embedded Content" name="htmlComp-iframe" width="100%" height="100%" allow="fullscreen" data-src="" src="<SOURCE_LINK>"></iframe>`

Note the sandbox attributes.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 information that helps understand why this error occurred:

- The [iframe HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) has an attribute called `sandbox` which applies many restrictions on the iframe

  - “When the attribute is set, **the content is treated as being from a unique origin**, forms and scripts are disabled, **links are prevented from targeting other browsing contexts**, and plugins are disabled” (1)
  - “The sandboxed navigation browsing context flag: This flag prevents content from navigating browsing contexts other than the sandboxed browsing context itself (or browsing contexts further nested inside it)…” (2)
- [Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy): HTTP header allows you to ensure a top-level document does not share a browsing context group with cross-origin documents. Its possible values are:

  - `unsafe-none`: This is the default value. Allows the document to be added to its opener's browsing context group unless the opener itself has a COOP of same-origin or same-origin-allow-popups
  - `same-origin-allow-popups`: Retains references to newly opened windows or tabs that either don't set COOP or that opt out of isolation by setting a COOP of unsafe-none
  - `same-origin`: **Isolates the browsing context exclusively to same-origin documents**. Cross-origin documents are not loaded in the same browsing context.”

---

**Root cause**

When the link is opened from the iframe, 2 things happen:

- The `sandbox` attribute is inherited and applied to the link → the link is now treated as being from a unique origin.
- Combined with Google's COOP header → the link is opened in a new browsing context

→ The link is blocked due to **links are prevented from targeting other browsing contexts** in sandboxed iframe

---

**Solution**

Add `allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox` to the `sandbox` attribute of the iframe. This way, the opened link would not be sandboxed

- `allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox`: Allows a sandboxed document to open new windows without forcing the sandboxing flags upon them. This will allow, for example, a third-party advertisement to be safely sandboxed without forcing the same restrictions upon the page the ad links to

---

**References:**

- (1) https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-sandbox
- (2) https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#sandboxed-navigation-browsing-context-flag